# Can i use ReactJS with AngularJS to take care of the 'view'?

Tags: angularjs, reactjs

We got an app written in AngularJS but we have run into performance issues as the app tries to load a large amount of data from the server and lets the user play around with it (read *a complex DOM*). Surfing around and reading about it seems that two-way data binding, intrinsically called $watch expressions etc of AngularJS is posing a problem that we are unable to surmount. And then we have come across fb's ReactJS that promises fast view rendering.

This has set us wondering if ReactJS could be used with AngularJS to just take care of the 'view' part. Would be very grateful if anyone could provide some insight or direction regarding this?

Thanks

Comment: I think your question has been answered?

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://single-spa.js.org/) tool (single-spa, a javascript framework for front-end microservices) allows you to use different libraries and frameworks combine. In this way, you can save your old business logic.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [ngReact](https://github.com/davidchang/ngReact)? I haven't tried it myself but it seems to do what you want (using React components in Angular).

Answer (score 0):

i'm playing with that now to combine angular directives with react, but for my app in pure angular on large data set, i used angulars for $compile and rendering and it works pretty fast, but data manipulation and whole building of this part of HTML is done by d3.js, maybe you can look on that lib...

Comment: Thanks.Came across the following example on using Angular with React but am running into issues https://github.com/petehunt/angularjs-tutorials/tree/master/directives/rating-bridged.It gives the following error message:
                 TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'FundooRating'

Looks like it does not recognize: 'window.FundooRating'.Tried using the following:

           React.renderComponent(React.window.FundooRating({id: 'fundooRating',scope: scope}), elem[0]);

At which it says:
                 TypeError: Cannot call method 'FundooRating' of undefined